# R: igraph: Testing the quality of multiple communities

Tags: r, igraph, modularity

In igraph 0.6.6, after finding communities with the infomap algorithm, which returns a set of communities (see below), I'm wondering how I can qualify them individually. The modularity returned with the communities object is that of the most modular partition. How can I compute the modularity of all them? Better yet, report and order the top n-best communities?

```
comms <- infomap.community(g, e.weights=normed_edge_weights,
                              v.weights=normed_node_freqs,
                              modularity=T, nb.trials=30)
modularity <- modularity(comms)
```

Comment: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2014-02/msg00014.html Cross posting is considered to be "not nice" by some, and these people might be less likely to answer your question. FYI.